# Access to global variable across modules and staticmethods in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, global-variables, static-methods

Assume two Python modules titled `GlobVars` and `MyModule`.

Module `GlobVars` is intended to supply the other module with the global variable `my_glob_var`.

```
# cat GlobVars.py
class getGlobVars:
    def __init__(self):
        global my_glob_var
        my_glob_var = 'World'
    def go(self):
        pass
```

Module `MyModule` contains a class with two functions (`_concat` and `getConcat`), one of which (i.e., `_concat`) is a staticmethod that attempts to access the aforementioned global variable. Function `getConcat` accesses the staticmethod and is supposed to return a concatenated string.

```
# cat MyModule.py
import GlobVars as GV
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
    @staticmethod
    def _concat(var2):
        GV.getGlobVars().go()
        return var2 + my_glob_var

    def getConcat(self):
        return MyClass._concat('Hello ')+self.var1
```

When I attempt to load both modules and execute function `getConcat`, the global variable does not seem to be properly accessed. Why is that and what is the solution?

```
import MyModule
import GlobVars
print MyModule.MyClass('!').getConcat()
# NameError: global name 'my_glob_var' is not defined
```

Comment: 1. Python globals aren't "global globals", they're only global to the module in which they're defined. 2. You only need the `global` keyword when you want to modify a global, you can read a global without the keyword (and you should avoid using modifiable globals anyway). 3. Since you're using Python 2 you should use new-style classes: make your classes inherit from `object`, otherwise you get the inferior old-style classes. (Python 3 only has new-style, so you don't need to explicitly inherit from `object`, but it's still nice to do so, since it makes it easier to back-port to Python 2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case you don't have to use `global` keyword nor `GlobVars` class.

Instead:

```
# cat GlobVars.py
my_glob_var = 'World'

# cat MyModule.py
import GlobVars as GV
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1

    @staticmethod
    def _concat(var2):
        return var2 + GV.my_glob_var

    def getConcat(self):
        return MyClass._concat('Hello ')+self.var1
```

By the way python docs have little section about sharing global vars across modules: https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=global#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The simplest solution often doesn't come to mind.